# Docker unable to restore postgres database sql file

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have followed below process to backup my database file.

image 1 :

[image]

Image 2 :

[image]

After click on backup , I got a file with name `resetmarathon_db.sql`

Then I have store this file in my project/DB directory

In `docker-compose.yml` file I have use volume like below example

```
volumes:
      - ./DB/resetmarathon_db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/resetmarathon_db.sql
```

This is the full section of docker-compose.yml file for postgres

```
resetmarathon_db:
    container_name: resetmarathon_db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: resetmarathon_db
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    hostname: resetmarathon_db
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - resetmarathon-network
    volumes:
      - ./DB/resetmarathon_db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/resetmarathon_db.sql
```

After build I'm getting only database table name with no any table.

How can I restore my sql file ?

My file and folder structure

[image]

Comment: It isn't an SQL file - it's a "custom" format (which is what you selected) backup file. You can restore it with pg_restore. If you want the docker auto-run stuff it presumably needs to be a genuine sql file.

Comment: Thanks @RichardHuxton after see your comment , I have downloaded plan sql file and it's working !!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the database before you execute your script

Here is a create database script which you can save as a file `init_dbScript.sql`

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS resetmarathon_db;
CREATE DATABASE resetmarathon_db;
```

Then volume it and make sure it will be executed before your script.

```
volumes:
  - ./DB/resetmarathon_db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/resetmarathon_db.sql
  - ./DB/init_dbScript.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init_dbScript.sql
```

Comment: after apply this volumes no any changes found.

Comment: @NiloyRony Could you try to add create database script in the begin of `resetmarathon_db.sql`? and make sure your script will be work in a empty database